# How to detect a variable change and get the value of the variable in c#

Tags: c#

I have made use of `property changed event` to assign a value to a `bool` value in an attempt to get the connectivity status.

However, I want to listen for this change of the variable from another class and perform some action. How can I achieve this in `C#` ?

```
private bool isDisconnected;

public bool IsDisconnected
{
    get { return isDisconnected; }
    set
    {
        isDisconnected = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("IsDisconnected");
    }

}

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

public override void OnConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, [GeneratedEnum] GattStatus status, [GeneratedEnum] ProfileState newState)
{
    base.OnConnectionStateChange(gatt, status, newState);

    if(newState == ProfileState.Connected)
    {
        isDisconnected = true;
        gatt.DiscoverServices();
    }

    else if(newState == ProfileState.Disconnected)
    {
        gatt.Close();
        isDisconnected = true;
        Log.Info("BLE", "Status: Disconnected");
    }

}
```

In another class which is basically a `Service`, I want to listen for the variable `IsDisconnected`. Please someone help me.

**My Service class:**

```
[return: GeneratedEnum]
public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, [GeneratedEnum] StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
{
    try
    {
        Toast.MakeText(this, "Background service started", ToastLength.Long);
        t = new Thread(() =>
        {
            Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                ConnectionListener gatt = new ConnectionListener ();
                gatt.PropertyChanged += (s, e) =>
                {
                    if (e.PropertyName == nameof(GattCallback.IsDisconnected))
                    {

                    }
                };

            });
        });

        t.Start();
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to subscribe to this event and when it's raised for `IsDisconnected` property act however you want. Information about which property the change concerns is contained within arguments that you receive when event is raised.

Comment: How to implement this any further ?

Comment: If this other class already has an access to the one with an event it goes like this `connectionListener.PropertyChanged += OnPropertyChanged` and `private void OnPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            if (args.PropertyName == nameof(connectionListener.IsDisconnected))
            {
                DoSomething();
            }
        }`

Comment: @yoger: I have added the code in my service above, but its not hitting the `if (e.PropertyName == nameof(GattCallback.IsDisconnected))` 

Can you please advise ?

Comment: Have you tried debugging to verify that the event is indeed raised? If so are property names valid?

Comment: Yes I've just put a breakpoint in the service. It gets hit when the app start. But when the connectivity changes, and the variable changes, it does not get hit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose the instance of your class is called `connection`. Then from another class you hook up the `PropertyChanged` event:

```
connection.PropertyChanged += (s,e) =>
{
   if (e.PropertyName == nameof(YourClass.IsDisconnected))
   { 
       //isDisconnected changed, perform your logic
   }
}
```

Of course this is just a sample code and it would be appropriate to move the event handling to a method if the two instances have different lifetime. By doing that you can later unsubscribe from the event so that you don't introduce memory leaks.

Also you need to update the `GattCallback` class to set the `IsDisconnected` property instead of the `isDisconnected` field in the `OnConnectionChange` method:

```
if(newState == ProfileState.Connected)
{
    IsDisconnected = false; //notice change true -> false
    gatt.DiscoverServices();
}

else if(newState == ProfileState.Disconnected)
{
    gatt.Close();
    IsDisconnected = true;
    Log.Info("BLE", "Status: Disconnected");
}
```

Also it seems you had a bug there - you were setting `IsDisconnected` to `true` in both cases, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: Basically my `Service` is the background service class in my App. 

Do you think it'll work ?

Comment: I have added the code in my service above, but its not hitting the `if (e.PropertyName == nameof(GattCallback.IsDisconnected))` 

Can you please advise ?

Comment: You must assign to the `IsDisconnected` property instead of `isDisconnected` field inside the `OnConnectionChange` method, so that the setter is executed and the `PropertyChanged` event fires.